# Distance sensor with 16x2 lcd display- ImportError: cannot import name lcddriver

Tags: python, sensor, python-3, raspi-config, lcd

Happy new year.
I am working on a personal project which involves a distance sensor and a LCD display. The distance sensor's data should ideally be displayed on the 16x2 LCD display. The codes for the sensor works. However, when I tried to import "lcddriver"(which contains codes for the LCD display) , it shows:

"ImportError: cannot import name lcddriver"

I cloned [please click on me to see the codes that I used...](https://github.com/jumejume1/pi-LCD-Ultrasonic) this into my raspberry pi terminal and "lcddriver" is in my file.
[image: file page]
[image: The first line in "nano-distance.py": import lcddriver]
[image: It did not work out and showed me the error]

this is how my code looks in "distance.py": https://github.com/jumejume1/pi-LCD-Ultrasonic/blob/master/distance-lcd.py

Why is there an import error?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the error is given because there is no module named **lcddriver.py** which is what **import lcddriver** will be looking for.

Rename **lcddriver** to **lcddriver.py**.