# "Attribute Error"- How to display data from distance sensor on lcd display?

Tags: python, sensor, python-3, raspi-config, lcd

I am trying to incorporate LCD display features with the codes that are already written for the sensor. "lcddriver.py" is in "lcd". "distance.py" contains codes for my distance sensor. [image: file]
This is the code that I used for the sensor:https://github.com/jumejume1/pi-LCD-Ultrasonic/blob/master/distance-lcd.py

The Pi shows that I had an error in terms of objects and attributes.

I wrote:

> `display = lcddriver.lcd()`

it showed:

> `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lcd'`

In order to display sensor data on LCD Display, how can I fix the problem?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's  a [lcd class instantiation](https://github.com/jumejume1/pi-LCD-Ultrasonic/blob/master/lcddriver.py) not an attribute call because you use '()' after lcd... I don't understand. Try to remove the `lcddriver.pyc` file if you have download the git project and restart your pyhthon code maybe ?

Comment: Also, your red arrow point to a file without any extensions. Try to rename `lcddriver.py`

Comment: Thank you very much! This photo was taken before I renamed it. I tried after deleting the lcddriver.pyc file but it didn't work.

Comment: @Ephemeral I think I missed a important step before importing "lcddriver" but I can't figure it out....

Comment: You're welcome. With the same error ?

Comment: yes. I tried to switch their position and wrote it as "display = lcd.lcddriver()" and it told me that "name lcd is undefined"

Comment: Download from git the original lcddriver.py file. Move it into your project directory. Run your disance script. If the module is correct , the module is compilated into `.pyc`

Comment: `display = lcddriver.lcd()` is used in `distance-lcd.py` on github. Put your distance code if you want more help.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. Happy new year to you

Comment: Thank you very much, to you too, a beautiful and happy new year.

Comment: I can see a [related question of your problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106812/distance-sensor-with-16x2-lcd-display-importerror-cannot-import-name-lcddriver) ... try: `from lcddriver import lcd` and not `from lcd import lcddriver`, the module name is `lcddriver` where your call the class named  `lcd`

Comment: Hello, I think I need more help. I can't upload pictures caused they are oversized. Do you have an email address or something? How can I send my code to you?Thank you

Comment: That question was asked by me as well haha

Comment: You can edit your question here and add your code. `share` ,`edit`, `flag` below your question.

Comment: it tells me that no module named lcddriver

Comment: the codes are in the link that I included in the question. Thank you!